# Instagram rate limits

Tags: instagram

I'm getting this error

FIELD   VALUE
code    429
error_type  OAuthRateLimitException
error_message   The maximum number of requests per hour has been exceeded.

How can I get more requests per hour . I mean more that 500/hr.

Comment: That's a lot of requests. What are you doing that requires 500 requests per hour per user?

Comment: I'm not sure what is happening. The instagram photos dissappear & I got the error message I have posted.

Comment: Well, what are you doing with the API? If you're doing something like an API call every time someone views your site, chances are you need to cache the response for a couple minutes. Would help with performance too.

Answer (score -1):

If you register your app and it gets accepted, you can do up to 5000/hr (per token).

You can read more here:
https://www.instagram.com/developer/limits/

Comment: How can I register my app?

Comment: Hi, I have my account in live mode now (approved), but I still receive 500/hr & not 5000/hr . Why? How can I fix it ?

Comment: I am downvoting this because the answer is 2 years old, the link doesn't work and people have asked questions and not been given help.

Comment: @KentondeJong the answer is 1.5 years old and is out of date. Why downvote the answer just because Instagram has changed how their program / api works?

Comment: @BrennerSpear I explained why I downvoted it. Update your answer and I will upvote it. The link is broken, people are looking for answers and you aren't giving them any.